# Openmanage failing to recognize firmware versions?

Tags: dell-openmanage

I'm running (what I believe) is the latest version of OpenManage. Every night it polls the various machines for firmware versions and compares them to what it believes are the latest available.

This is all well and good except that it's not getting the stamps correct. In just about every case where it's reporting upgrades are required, I've already done them. 2x - even 3x just to be sure!

When I rerun the patch it tells me that it's up to date. So why isn't OM getting the same info? Is there some secondary step that I've missed? Many of these patches are recognized so whatever this mystery step is, it isn't universal.

Anyone else encountered this problem? Solution?

Comment: OpenManage is a "suite" of components. There's OpenManage Server Administrator (which is the managed node component) and there's OpenManage Essentials (which is the management node component). I'm assuming that you're referring to OpenManage Essentials, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It's the browser based app that shows inventory, some pie charts with node information, etc.